# (Unity3D) Difference between MultiplyPoint and MultiplyPoint3x4

Tags: matrix, vector, unity-game-engine, 3d

Unity docs as unhelpful as usual.

MultiplyPoint3x4 is simply a transformation matrix - which i've tested using dot product manually and had the same output.

However I'm very confused over what differs between standard matrix multiplication in [MultiplyPoint3x4](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.MultiplyPoint3x4.html)and that used by [MultiplyPoint](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Matrix4x4.MultiplyPoint.html). 
I'm told the source code licence is available, but I only need one function.

Any advice welcome.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was curious about this as well. What steps of a matrix multiplication could Unity possibly be skipping? The optimization is possible because a scaling and rotation needs only a 3x3 matrix and another vector for the translation. So part of the full 4x4 matrix is unused and can be ignored in  the multiplication.

```
public Vector3 MultiplyPoint(Vector3 v)
{
    Vector3 vector3;
    vector3.x =  ( m00 *  v.x +  m01 *  v.y +  m02 *  v.z) + m03;
    vector3.y =  ( m10 *  v.x +  m11 *  v.y +  m12 *  v.z) + m13;
    vector3.z =  ( m20 *  v.x +  m21 *  v.y +  m22 *  v.z) + m23;
    float num = 1f / ( ( m30 *  v.x +  m31 *  v.y +  m32 *  v.z) + m33); // this is 1/1=1 when m30, m31, m32 = 0 and m33 = 1
    vector3.x *= num; // so then multiplying by 1 is pointless..
    vector3.y *= num;
    vector3.z *= num;
    return vector3;
}
```

This is a full 4x4 * 4x1 matrix multiplication, and then scaling the x y z of the result by the w of the result.

[image: general multiply pointformula]

This is necessary for projective transformations, but not for rotation and scaling.

This is why they have the faster 3x4 version. It assumes the w component of each column is 0 and skips that bottom row of multiplication and scaling, because the resulting w is always 1.

```
public Vector3 MultiplyPoint3x4(Vector3 v)
{
    Vector3 vector3;
    vector3.x =  ( m00 *  v.x +  m01 *  v.y +  m02 *  v.z) + m03;
    vector3.y =  ( m10 *  v.x +  m11 *  v.y +  m12 *  v.z) + m13;
    vector3.z =  ( m20 *  v.x +  m21 *  v.y +  m22 *  v.z) + m23;
    return vector3;
}
```

This function is equivalent to multiplying matrices which look like:

[image: fast multiply point formula]

The source code was referenced from this page: https://github.com/jameslinden/unity-decompiled/blob/master/UnityEngine/UnityEngine/Matrix4x4.cs

Comment: Great reply! Hopefully others will stumble on this. Certainly is just an optimization. Makes sense when there is only a select use case for the w component. Still, I think they could of handled it with an override or interface on unity engine backend, not confuse us :)

Comment: Agreed. They should have at least explained in the documentation why it was limited.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned in the docs, MultiplyPoint3x4 is basically a faster version of MultiplyPoint, considering the matrix is a regular 3D Xform. As to exactly how it's faster, as you may have guessed, unless you have access to the source code, it's in your best interests simply to trust what the devs themselves say. You could also try posting on the Unity forums for a better chance of getting a mod/dev to notice your interest.

I trust them blindly all the time.
And then I fault them for it if I ever have evidence. It's an easy flow ;)

I hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, however I'm quite ware. Unfortunately the reason why MultiplyPoint gives me the correct output compared to multiplypoint3*4 is what's stopping me from transferring to GPU.
Good suggestion with unity forums, it's certainly worth a shot.
Many Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

found it! - note you do not need the unity source licence with this!

```cs
    public Vector3 MultiplyPoint( Vector3 v )
    {
        Vector3 result;
        result.x = this.m00 * v.x + this.m01 * v.y + this.m02 * v.z + this.m03;
        result.y = this.m10 * v.x + this.m11 * v.y + this.m12 * v.z + this.m13;
        result.z = this.m20 * v.x + this.m21 * v.y + this.m22 * v.z + this.m23;
        float num = this.m30 * v.x + this.m31 * v.y + this.m32 * v.z + this.m33;
        num = 1 / num;
        result.x *= num;
        result.y *= num;
        result.z *= num;
        return result;
    }
```